# Validating a dropdown bound to a SelectList object using data annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to follow best practices for validations in ASP.NET Core. I have a contact form with the page bound to a view model.

**Model**

```
public class ViewModel {
    ...
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select a city")]
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    public SelectList CityList { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
<select id="input-request-type" class="form-control" asp-for="CityID" asp-items="@Model.CityList">
    <option value="" hidden disabled selected>Select a city</option>
</select>
<span asp-validation-for="CityID"></span>
```

This converts to something like this in HTML:

```
<select class="input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="Select a city" name="CityID">
    <option value="" hidden="" disabled="" selected="">Select a city</option>
    <option value="9">Toronto</option>
    <option value="12">New York</option>
</select>
```

The problem with the above code is that the validation does not trigger an error. My guess is that the validation still detects a value from the submission even though it is a blank string.

**What I tried:**

I tried modifying the data annotations on the model like so:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
public string Name { get; set; }
...
[BindRequired]
public int CityID { get; set; }
public SelectList CityList { get; set; }
```

This shows a validation error, but it shows `Name is required`. It picks up the first validation error available, but not quite what I wanted, so I changed it to the following:

```
...
[BindRequired]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Select a city")]
public int CityID { get; set; }
public SelectList CityList { get; set; }
```

This also shows an error but it completely ignores the error message I want. The output is `A value for the 'CityID' property was not provided.`

Any idea on how to properly show the error message I want? I can't seem to find any documentation on this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can override the message on the view itself.

**Model**

```
[BindRequired]
public int CityID { get; set; }
public SelectList CityList { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
<style>
    .field-validation-valid {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<select id="input-request-type" class="form-control" asp-for="CityID" asp-items="@Model.CityList">
    <option value="" hidden disabled selected>Select a city</option>
</select>
<span asp-validation-for="CityID">Select a city</span>
```

The span element for the validation transforms into the following depending if the value is valid or not:

```
// valid
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="CityID" data-valmsg-replace="true">
    Select a city
</span>

// invalid
<span class="field-validation-error text-danger" data-valmsg-for="CityID" data-valmsg-replace="true">
    Select a city
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

In ViewModel class, add this annotation before CityID Property:

```
[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "This field is required!")]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by simply combining nullable property definition and Required attribute:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "City is Required.")]
public int? CityID { get; set; }
```